# How To Link Stylesheet Using Wordpress ENQUEUE Function

Tags: wordpress, enqueue

function webzone_sahil( ){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri( ) );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'webzone_sahil');

Comment: Hi.  Can you add an actual question to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
//Main-theme                    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_second_style_sheet' );
function wpsites_second_style_sheet() {

       wp_register_style( 'second-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'css/second-style.css', array(), '20130608');
       wp_enqueue_style( 'second-style' );    

}


//child-theme
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_second_style_sheet' );
function wpsites_second_style_sheet() {

       wp_register_style( 'second-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'css/second-style.css', array(), '20130608');
       wp_enqueue_style( 'second-style' );    

}
```